# laravel eloquent leftjoin query overwriting model value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have models `user_account` which has a relationship of `channel` which inturn has a relationship `company`. All user_account, channel and company contain the column `title`. I'm trying to pull user account models by company title, and to do this I'm using:

```
return $q->leftJoin('channels', 'user_accounts.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id')->leftJoin('channel_companies', 'channels.channel_company_id', '=', 'channel_companies.id')->where('channel_companies.title', $companyTitle);
```

However, on return, the user_account.title property is overwritten by company.title. Why and how do I avoid this?

Comment: The values are being overwritten because each table is returning the column name as a key / value pair. You can use a `select` something like this `$q->select('user_account.channel.title as channel_title')` to prevent the overwriting.

Comment: this is how to work around it, but why is it returning the title in the user_account object though? shouldn't it just return the channel_company title in the channel_company object?

Comment: @Rafee that will only return the user_account.title for the result which is certainly not what i want.

Comment: @MattMcAlister I don't think you can access relations like that in eqloquent queries? Either way, it states there's no such field

Comment: @user3791372 Haha, you're right. My bad there. It'd just be the `channels.title as channel_title` instead since the tables are joined.

Comment: @MattMcAlister nope, "However, on return, the user_account.title property is overwritten by company.title", not by channel title!

Comment: Just change the select to have `user_account.title as user_account_title` or something, rather.

Comment: If you need to prevent override you need to `select` specific column with `alias` if multiple table contain same column name